# Nested roots with common baseline to minimize unnecessary white space

Tags: math-mode, symbols, vertical-alignment, amsmath

I am teaching from a precalc text that included the following in regards to nested roots:

[image]

I thought this looked pretty nice so I tried to reproduce it, but I ran into a few issues:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Really ugly: 
\[
\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}}}.
\]
Not quite as ugly but still not ideal:
\[
\sqrt{\smash[b]{2\sqrt{\smash[b]{2\sqrt{\smash[b]{2\sqrt{\smash[b]{2}}}}}}}}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to reproduce the textbook example? In mine, the second example looks much closer to that in the text but still off a good bit. [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/49833/align-sqrt-with-baseline-of-other-mathematical-input?rq=1) inspired my use of `smash` but I imagine I may not be using it correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: This doesn't do it, but may help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148127/a-version-of-smash-that-interpolates-between-the-true-height-depth-and-the-text

Comment: @JPi Thanks for the reference. Will try to digest soon and see if I can work out a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**REVISED ANSWER**

Pull out the `scalerel` magic, and employ parameters `\depthgrowth` and `\heightgrowth` that define the growth in the `\sqrt` depth/height per nesting.
The first result is with `\depthgrowth` at 0pt, `\heightgrowth` at 1pt.  For the second/third examples, `\depthgrowth` at 1pt, `\heightgrowth` at 1.5pt

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,scalerel}
\def\depthgrowth{0pt}
\def\heightgrowth{1pt}
\newsavebox\zbox
\newcommand\zsqrt[1]{%
  \ignoremathstyle
  \savebox\zbox{$#1\rule{0pt}{.7\baselineskip}$}%
  \stretchrel*{\sqrt{\phantom{#1}\kern0.5pt}}%
              {\rule[-\dimexpr\dp\zbox+\depthgrowth]{0pt}{%
                \dimexpr\ht\zbox+\dp\zbox+\depthgrowth+\heightgrowth}}%
  \kern-\wd\zbox\textstyle#1%
}
\begin{document}
\[
 \zsqrt{34\zsqrt{23\zsqrt{2\zsqrt{2}}}}
\]
\def\depthgrowth{1pt}
\def\heightgrowth{1.5pt}
\[
 \zsqrt{34\zsqrt{23\zsqrt{2\zsqrt{2}}}}
\]
\[
 \zsqrt{\frac{3}{4}\zsqrt{\frac{2}{3}\zsqrt{2\zsqrt{\frac{1}{2}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

Bottom line: I just got lucky here.  I found that the height of the cross-bar changes drastically for small changes in `\vs` argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\vs[1]{\rule{0pt}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\[
\sqrt{\vs{10pt}2\smash{\sqrt{\vs{8.2pt}2\smash{\sqrt{\vs{8.1pt}2\smash{\sqrt{2}}}}}}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This definitely looks nicer. This is very nitpicky, does it not look like the first and last root signs have the same baseline but the middle two are off a fair amount? The textbook example seems to have an entirely constant baseline which seems to be quite difficult to obtain. Maybe I can fool around with the new command you gave and see if changing a few things will help.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Good catch.  As I said, I was lucky to get this far, but I will keep trying.

Comment: @DanielW.Farlow Please see revision.

Comment: Wow, awesome work! I'm going to try to really understand your revision, but it looks great. Thanks!